# How do I change fields a slice of structs using reflect?

Tags: go

I have the following https://play.golang.org/p/TlHCX29QZr

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type A struct {
    Name string
    Age  int
}

func change(a interface{}) {
    aa := reflect.Indirect(reflect.ValueOf(a))

    for i := 0; i < aa.NumField(); i++ {
        field := aa.Field(i)

        switch field.Interface().(type) {
        case string:
            field.Set(reflect.ValueOf("fred"))
        case int:
            field.Set(reflect.ValueOf(54))
        default:
            fmt.Println("unknown field")
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    a := &A{"bob", 120}
    b := []*A{}
    c := []struct {
        Alias  string
        Months int
    }{}

    d := []struct {
        First  string
        Years int
    }{
        {"james", 22},
        {"ricky", 32},
        {"bobby", 12},
        {"rachel", 82}, 
    }


    change(a)
    fmt.Println(a) // want &A{"fred", 54}

    change(b)
    fmt.Println(b) // want []*A{&A{"fred", 54}}

    change(c)
    fmt.Println(c) // want []struct{struct{"fred", 54}}

    change(d)
    fmt.Println(d) // want []struct{struct{"fred", 54}, struct{"fred", 54}, struct{"fred", 54}, struct{"fred", 54}}
}
```

As you can see, some of the variables are an empty slice and some are not. For those that are empty, I need to add 1 struct of {"fred", 54}. For those slices that are not empty I need to change all values to {"fred", 54}. I do not know in advance what the fields are...only that if there is a string field the value should be "fred" and if an int field 54.

I'm able to change the value of "a" but everything else fails with "panic: reflect: call of reflect.Value.NumField on slice Value". I'm not sure where to go on this. Thank you!

Comment: You're passing in two different `reflect.Kind`s, structs and slices, in case of slices you cannot use `NumField`, you have to iterate over its contents, make sure that those are structs and then you can call `NumField` on those.

Comment: You also logically want to do 2 different things here. In b and c you want to "append" a single value if the slice is empty, while in the other's you want to modify the values.

Comment: @mkopriva how do I iterate over a slice of empty anonymous struct to get the field names?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated in the comments, you cannot use `NumField` on a slice, since that method is allowed only for `reflect.Value`s that are of kind `reflect.Struct`.

So if you want to handle both kinds you need to know which one was passed in.

```
if rv.Kind() == reflect.Struct {
    changeStruct(rv)
}
if rv.Kind() == reflect.Slice {
    changeSlice(rv)
}
```

Now, if you want to append to an empty slice, you either have to pass in a pointer to the slice or you have to return the new slice.

```
change(&b)
change(&c)
```

Also, to be able to initialize that single element that you want to append you first need to know its type, to get the type of a slice's element you first get the slice's `reflect.Type` and then use its `Elem` method to get the type of the slice's element. With that type you can then use `reflect.New` to allocate a new value of that type and append it to the slice.

```
var elem reflect.Value

// rv is the slice
typ := rv.Type().Elem()
if typ.Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
    elem = reflect.New(typ.Elem())
}
if typ.Kind() == reflect.Struct {
    elem = reflect.New(typ).Elem()
}
```

To then loop over a slice you can use the `reflect.Value.Len` and `reflect.Value.Index` methods.

```
ln := rv.Len()
for i := 0; i < ln; i++ {
    changerv(rv.Index(i))
}
```

---

The code:

```
func change(a interface{}) {
    rv := reflect.ValueOf(a)
    changerv(rv)
}

func changerv(rv reflect.Value) {
    if rv.Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
        rv = rv.Elem()
    }

    if rv.Kind() == reflect.Struct {
        changeStruct(rv)
    }
    if rv.Kind() == reflect.Slice {
        changeSlice(rv)
    }
}

// assumes rv is a slice
func changeSlice(rv reflect.Value) {
    ln := rv.Len()
    if ln == 0 && rv.CanAddr() {
        var elem reflect.Value

        typ := rv.Type().Elem()
        if typ.Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
            elem = reflect.New(typ.Elem())
        }
        if typ.Kind() == reflect.Struct {
            elem = reflect.New(typ).Elem()
        }

        rv.Set(reflect.Append(rv, elem))
    }

    ln = rv.Len()
    for i := 0; i < ln; i++ {
        changerv(rv.Index(i))
    }
}

// assumes rv is a struct
func changeStruct(rv reflect.Value) {
    if !rv.CanAddr() {
        return
    }
    for i := 0; i < rv.NumField(); i++ {
        field := rv.Field(i)

        switch field.Kind() {
        case reflect.String:
            field.SetString("fred")
        case reflect.Int:
            field.SetInt(54)
        default:
            fmt.Println("unknown field")
        }
    }
}
```

The [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/UjkjLDt3vT).